How can i add a new folder on the same level as another folder in which i have initialized git?
I was working on a folder client and pushing it constantly to git suddenly after few days i reminded that i forget to make a backend folder and pushed only client folder to the git . Now can anyone tell me how to resolve this. My client folder is inside Project folder and and i also want backend to be in project folder on same level as client.

I have no idea what you are asking. What is your directory structure? Where is your .git directory? How many Git repositories do you have? Why can't you simply mv (move) the directory into your repo and add it?

project folder consist of client and backend but i have intialized git inside client only

You could probably hack it by moving the .git folder one level out. You might be able to make git recognize that as you having moved everything into a folder.

Assuming your directory structure looks like this:
/
  client
    .git
    your_files
  backend
    your_files

Then the simplest solution is probably to move the files, create a new commit, then copy over the new files:
cd /client
mkdir client
git mv * client/ # make sure to copy any hidden files too
git commit -m 'Move files to client directory'
copy -a ../backend backend
git add backend
git commit -m 'Add backend files'

Eventually, rename your top-level client directory to something else, e.g. my_project.
I'm pretty sure there are solutions involving filter-repo, filter-branch, or subtree merges, but I don't think they are worth the effort here. Simply move your files and then copy/move your other directory into the repo.
